# ActiveRecord - Callback after all transactions have finished being commited to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my model. I want the set_variations method to run only when ALL the transactions have finished being committed to the db.. With the current after_commit, it runs that method after each commit.. I was thinking of maybe a counter of some sort, but I don't know how many new products are added until after the process finishes.. How to do this?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :merchant

  validates :sellersku, uniqueness: true
  validates :asin, uniqueness: true

  include Send

  before_save     :split_off 
  after_commit    :set_variations


  def split_off
    @merchant = self.merchant_id
    self.five_of_asin = self.asin[0,5]
    self.twenty_of_title = self.title[0,20]
  end

  def set_variations
    binding.pry
    Product.where(merchant_id: @merchant).find_each do |merch|
      variations = merch.group(:twenty_of_title).count
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why can't you count products? I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Where your transactions are called? Can't you create a set_variations there and call after your transactions, since you are using Product and not an instance of Product?

Comment: Yea that's what I ended up doing.. First I was able to count the products I'm pulling, and then I called the method outside of the model.. so it worked.. thanks!